# datepicker not displaying in dynamic input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an input which has name="date" as identifier. This is inside of a while loop to generate dynamic data. What is happening, is that when the loop is run, the datepicker only works on the first input. It displays when each input has focus, but when I click a date, it always inserts it into the first input field. How can I correct this?. Thanks

I have placed code at the following fiddle link.

jsfiddle.net/mNFrb/

UPDATE: I have placed code at the above link. I cannot do hyper link because it tells me link not relevant when I edit, whatever that means.

Comment: provide some code or fiddle link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting the name date on each single input? You should not have several inputs with the same name. Use a unique name for each input, but you can use the same class for all of them and set the jquery datepicker to make them datapickers based on the class.

To give more detailed information, I will need to see you code as it is now, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: How do I give each input a unique name. Also, how would I gather values when data is passed for processing. Thanks

Comment: What about just appending the number from the lopp you use to generate the inputs? So the first one is "date1", the second "date2" and so on.

Comment: Could you please supply sample.

Comment: According to you code sample, I would use a for loop instead of a while loop. In a for loop you have a loop variable (for example `i`) that you can use when you create the input. Set the id of the input to `"date"+i`, and class to `"date"`. Then in your javascript, use `".date"` instead og `"#date"` when creating the datepickers.

Comment: I wonder if you could help with the coding as I am quite new to php. Also, when i process data using post or get, what value do I check for? would it still be name. thanks